# In Django, is it better to store complex chaining save methods in models, or in views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Lets say I have models similar to something like this:

```
from django.db import models, transaction


class X(models.Model):
    ...

    def do_something(self):
        ...


class Y(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def do_something(self):
        ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Y, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x.do_something()
        self.x.save()


class Z(models.Model):
    ...
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Z, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.y.do_something()
        self.y.save()
```

In other words, if a `Z` object is saved, its referenced `Y` object is updated and saved, which in turn saves its referenced `X` object. Right now, as it clear from the code, the complex save process is stored entirely in the models module.

Anyway, my question is this: should this sort of logic be stored in views instead? Like there could be a view like so:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def my_view(request, z_pk):
    z = Z.objects.select_related('y__x').get(pk=z_pk)
    z.save()

    y = z.y
    y.do_something()
    y.save()

    x = y.x
    x.do_something()
    x.save()

    ...
```

Obviously, for the above scenario, the model module would be simplified into something like this:

```
from django.db import models, transaction


class X(models.Model):
    ...

    def do_something(self):
        ...


class Y(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def do_something(self):
        ...


class Z(models.Model):
    ...
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Which one of these approaches is best practices? I could not find anything particular to this in the docs. I apologize if this question is a matter of preference thing. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to keep this type of logic in the model itself for a couple of reasons.

1. Testing. It's easier to test just the model without getting a view involved in order to verify the logic.
2. Reuse. While you may think you only need this logic in one view now, that is almost never the case. The same logic may end up being used from another view, a management command, etc. in the future. Keeping the logic in the model makes it much easier to reuse.
3. Consistency. This is related to reuse but if you always need the downstream side effects on the other models when saving `Z` by keeping things in the model you are ensuring those effects are not missed by future authors when saving `Z`.

Comment: Makes sense. However, wouldn't you be forgoing the use of `select_related()` by overridding the `save()` methods?

Comment: You can still call `select_related` as you've done in your view code before calling `z.save()`. So `my_view` would look the same without the lines after `z.save()`.